# Duda, necesito ayuda en el siguiente ejercicio

Tags: c, funciones, matrices

el siguiente ejercicio me pide lo siguiente:

3. Se quiere controlar el número de habitantes de un edificio con 6 pisos y 4 puertas (A, B, C, y
   D) en cada piso. Realizar un programa que introduzca aleatoriamente (entre 1 y 10) el número
   de habitantes de cada puerta del edificio. El programa debe decir:

   a) La vivienda (piso y puerta) que más habitantes tiene del edificio.

   b) El piso que más habitantes tiene de todo el edificio.

   c) La puerta que más habitantes tiene de todo el edificio.

   d) La media de habitantes de cada piso.

   e) La media de habitantes por puerta.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_FILAS 6
#define N_COLUMNAS 4

int mostrarMenu(void);
void leer_matriz(void);
void escribir_matriz (void);
void piso_mas_habitantes(void);
void puerta_mas_habitantes(void);
void media_pisos(void);
void media_puerta(void);

int main(void)
{
    int matriz[N_FILAS][N_COLUMNAS];
    int opcion;
    int leer,escribir,max_piso,max_puerta,med_pisos,med_puerta;

    opcion=mostrarMenu();

    switch (opcion)
    {
    case 1:
        leer=void leer_matriz();
        escribir=void escribir_matriz();
        printf("La matriz es:\n");
        break;
    case 2:
        max_piso=piso_mas_habitantes();
        printf("El piso con mas habitantes es:\n");
        break;
    case 3:
        max_puerta=puerta_mas_habitantes();
        printf("La puerta con mas habitantes es:\n");
        break;
    case 4:
        med_pisos=media_pisos();
        printf("La media de pisos es:\n");
        break;
    case 5:
        med_puerta=media_puerta();
        printf("La media de puertas es:\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Fin del programa.");

    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int mostrarMenu(void)
{
    int opcion;

    printf("MENU DEL EJERCICIO \n");
 printf("============================ \n\n\n");
 printf("1 - Leer y escribir matriz. \n");
 printf("2 - La vivienda (piso y puerta) que más habitantes tiene del edificio. \n");
 printf("3 - El piso que más habitantes tiene de todo el edificio. \n\n\n");
 printf("4 - La puerta que más habitantes tiene de todo el edificio. \n");
 printf("5 - La media de habitantes de cada piso. \n");
 printf("6 - La media de habitantes por puerta. \n");
 printf("Opcion: ");
 scanf("%d",&opcion);
 return (opcion);
}

void leer_matriz(int matriz[N_FILAS][N_COLUMNAS])
{
    int i,j;
    int leer;
      srand(time(NULL));
      for(i=0;i<N_FILAS;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N_COLUMNAS;j++){
            matriz[i][j]=1+rand()%10;
            printf(" %i ",matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

 void escribir_matriz (int matriz[N_FILAS][N_COLUMNAS])
 {
      int i,j;
      for(i=0;i<N_FILAS;i++)
      {
      printf("\n");
      for(j=0;j<N_COLUMNAS;j++)
      printf(" %i ", matriz[i][j]);
      }
}

void piso_mas_habitantes(int matriz[N_FILAS][N_COLUMNAS])
{
    int i,j, aux[7]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int max_piso;
    int a=0, b=0;

    for (j=0;j<N_COLUMNAS;j++){
        for (i=0;i<N_FILAS;i++){
    aux[j]+=matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<7;i++){
        if (aux[i]>aux[i+1]&&aux[i]>a){
            a=aux[i];
            b=i;
        }
    }
    return max_piso;
}

void puerta_mas_habitantes(int matriz[N_FILAS][N_COLUMNAS])
{
    int i,j, aux[4]={0,0,0,0};
    int a=0, b=0;
    int max_puerta;
    char c[4]={'A','B','C','D'};

        for (i=0;i<N_FILAS;i++){
            for (j=0;j<N_COLUMNAS;j++){
                aux[i]+=matriz[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (i=0;i<4;i++){
            if (aux[i] > aux[i+1] && aux[i]>a){
                a=aux[i];
                b=i;
            }
        }
        return max_puerta;
}

void media_pisos(int matriz[N_FILAS][N_COLUMNAS])
{
    int i,j, aux[7]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int med_pisos;
    float a;

        for (j=0;j<N_COLUMNAS;j++){
        for (i=0;i<N_FILAS;i++){
    aux[j]+=matriz[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<7;i++){
        a=aux[i]/4.0;
    }
    return med_pisos;
}

void media_puerta(int matriz[N_FILAS][N_COLUMNAS])
{
    int i,j, aux[4]={0,0,0,0};
    int med_puerta;
    float a;
    char b[4]={'A','B','C','D'};

    for (i=0;i<N_FILAS;i++){
            for (j=0;j<N_COLUMNAS;j++){
                aux[i]+=matriz[i][j];
            }
        }

    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        a=aux[i]/7.0;
    }return med_puerta;
}
```

Comment: Fallo mío, toda la razón¡ Pues básicamente uno de los errores es que a la hora de llamar a las funciones en el switch me pone "too few arguments", ese es el primer error que me ha aparecido.

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

como estas?
Mira, estuve revisando tu código y tiene muchos errores conceptuales.

1) Cuando se declara una funcion se realiza de la siguiente manera:

```
[Tipo de dato devuelto] Nombre_Func(Argumentos);
```

Esto significa que si queres que te retorne, por ejemplo, piso_mas_habitantes(), deberia retornar un int, no un void.

```
int piso_mas_habitantes();
```

2) Dentro de las funciones que utilizar return, utilizas una variable no utilizada dentro de la funcion, y tampoco definida, motivo por el cual te va a retornar basura(al declarar una variable NO se crea con el contenido en 0, sino que contiene basura).
Siguiendo el ejemplo de piso_mas_habitantes(), retornas max_piso, y en el codigo asignas el piso con max habitantes a la variable b, entonces deberias retornar b.

3) Dentro de la funcion leer_matriz() entiendo que inserta aleatoriamente los datos dentro de la matriz creada, para que funcione dicha funcion, deberias pasarle por referencia la matriz a la funcion. Si le envias solo una copia, al terminar de ejecutar la funcion no va a guardarte ningun dato.
Además, incluis la funcion

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

algo que es correcto pero para que funcione la funcion time() deberias incluir la libreria time.h

```
#include <time.h>
```

4) Dentro del switch utilizas printf() para visualizar la variable que devuelve la funcion invocada previamente(continuamos con el ejemplo de piso_mas_habitantes) deberias utilizar el printf utilizando %d e indicando que variable queres imprimir:

```
printf("El piso con mas habitantes es: %d",max_piso);
```

5) Dentro de case 1 asignas a una variable leer el retorno de una funcion que no retorna nada, eso te va a generar otro problema al compilar.

6) Para los valores de retorno de las funciones que calculan la media de los pisos, deberia retornar un float, ya que si queres retornar un int, te "recorta" la parte decimal, es decir, si la media es 2,8 te retorna 2.

Espero que te sean de ayuda los puntos mencionados y te esperamos nuevamente para cualquier otra consulta.

Saludos